# Calculating time complexity using T(n) method?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

How may I calculate the time complexity of `f()` using `T(n)` method?

```
int f (int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return 1;
    return f(f(n-1));
}
```

**What I did till now?**

```
T(n)=T(T(n-1))=T(T(T(n-2)))=T(T(T(T(n-3))))...
```

Plus, I know that for every n>=1 the function always returns 1

And why changing the last line from:

`return f(f(n-1));`

to:

`return 1+f(f(n-1));`

would change time complexity (**Note: It's will change the complexity from n to 2^n for sure**)?

Comment: it will not change the complexity.

Comment: @ChungHuang it will change it from n to 2^n

Comment: no, only plus 1 does not make the change of complexity. you should try with a large number of n to test it. I am sure.

Comment: I tried setting a counter and when n=8 the first code returned with counter = 15 but after the edit it's 255!

Comment: Which proves my point, plus the complexity was verified to be 2^n by a lecturer in harvard

Comment: Your recurrence relation for the time complexity is wrong. It's T(n) = T(n-1) + T(f(n-1)). That's why changing f changes the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity changes, because the function does not `return 1;` always because of the `+1`.

For `return T(T(n-1));` the second `T` call will always be called with `1`, which will be only 1 more call. The number of calls are `2*n-1`, therefore complexity O(n).

For `return 1 + T(T(n-1));` not all calls to `T` will result in `1`, `T(3)` will result in `3` with `7` calls. So the second call depend on the value of `n`. Incrementing `n` will lead to doubled calls. The number of calls are `2^n - 1`, therefore complexity O(2^n). Here you can see the number of calls: https://ideone.com/1KEAkU

first version (T always return 1):

```
              T(4)
    T(1)                   T(3)
                     T(1)         T(2)
                              T(1)    T(1)
```

You can see that the left call (the outer one) will always be called with `1` and the tree does not continue there.

second version (T does not always return 1):

```
                    T(4)
          T(3)                   T(3)
   T(2)        T(2)         T(2)        T(2)
T(1) T(1)   T(1) T(1)    T(1) T(1)   T(1)  T(1)
```

Here you can see that because of the changed return value `T(n) == n` the second `T` calls doubles the number of calls.

The space complexity does not increase because the recursions depth does not change, both `T(4)` graphs have 4 lines and for the second tree the left part can only execute after the right part finished completely. e.g. for both `T(4)` the maximum number of `T` functions running are `4`.

Comment: ״The number of calls are 2^n - 1״ may you explain that more? Plus why this didn't affect space complexity from n to 2^n? the number of calls got bigger then the space will be bigger

Answer (score 0):

Adding any constant C to your program, would not change the complexity. In general, even after adding 5 new statements that do not contain the variable n wouldn't change the complexity either. For this program **complexity = n**, since you know that this will run at most n times.

Comment: you are wrong adding the constant would change the complexity from n to 2^n

Answer (score 0):

The (correct) recurrence relation for the time complexity is:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(f(n-1))
```

That's because to compute f(n), first you compute f(n-1) (cost T(n-1)) and then call f with the argument f(n-1) (cost T(f(n-1))).

When f(n) always returns 1, this results in T(n) = T(n-1) + 1, which solves to T(n) = Theta(n).

When the return statement of `f` is changed to `return 1 + f(f(n-1))`, then `f(n)` returns `n` for n>=1 (by a simple proof by induction).

Then the time complexity is T(n) = T(n-1) + T(f(n-1)) = T(n-1) + T(n-1) = 2T(n-1), which solves to T(n) = Theta(2^n).

(As an amusing side note, if you change `if(n==1)return 1;` to `if(n==1)return 0;` in the second case (with the +1)), then the time complexity is Theta(Fib(n)) where Fib(n) is the n'th fibonacci number).